# How do I print the next maximum element each time in a constant array?

Tags: c

For example, const array of integers is {88, 2, 90, 1, 4} and the printed output would be 
90 88 4 2 1 
I'm really confused since the requirement is O(n^2) in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `O(N^2)` solution you could do any form of sorting in descending order and print out accordingly.

You use `qsort()` in `<stdlib.h>` OR
write your own sorting algorithm. A few example to get you started:

1. Selection Sort
2. Insertion Sort
3. Bubble Sort

More advance sorting algorithm such as QuickSort, MergeSort can possibly give better time complexity improvements.

Comment: `qsort()` is hard to beat for time complexity. Generally implemented as a quicksort until the number partitions falls below some number ~16 and then a selection sort to finish. `qsort()` can't be beat by a code-your-own sort from a tried-and-tested solution standpoint.